# SUBQUERY (from a different table) in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to execute an NESTED query/SUBQUERY in SQL. The second query (or the Subquery is from a different table). I tried the below query, but it fails throwing an error 'relation does not exist'. Eventhough the query explains for itself, how should I address this problem?.

```
 SELECT 
      key 

    FROM 
      user_details 

    WHERE 
      user_id = (SELECT * FROM company_details WHERE type ='ABC');
```

Comment: How do `user_details` and `company_details` relate to each other? Please [edit] your question add the definition of the tables some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted text_ please, [no screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Use 'in' instead of '=':-

Rel_user_id is the relation between user_details  and company_details

```
 SELECT 
      key 

    FROM 
      user_details 

    WHERE 
      user_id in (SELECT distinct Rel_user_id FROM company_details WHERE type ='ABC');
```

Comment: 'company_details' is a different table than 'user_details'

Comment: Really? `user_id in(*)` ?

Comment: The distinct in the sub-query is useless

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  key 

FROM 
  user_details ud

WHERE 
  exists (SELECT 1 FROM company_details cd 
   WHERE cd.type ='ABC' and cd.Rel_user_id  = ud.user_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      ud.key 

    FROM 
         user_details ud
    JOIN company_details cd ON ud.user_id = cd.Rel_user_id

    WHERE cd.type ='ABC'
```